# Why wasn't Jiraya able to use Sage mode completely?

Tags: naruto

As shown in Shippuden, Fukasaku, one of the two Great Sage Toads says that Naruto has surpassed his master.

Jiraiya was not able to completely enter into sage mode, and as such only had a partial toad-like appearance.

This is what I read from [Naruto Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Jiraiya#Senjutsu):

> Jiraiya didn't like Sage Mode because it gave him a more toad-like appearance, with longer marks along the sides of his face, a goatee, a larger nose with warts, webbed hands and feet and sharp teeth, all of which made him unappealing to girls. This appearance is due to Jiraiya not having complete mastery over the technique.

But I don't think this was the only reason for not mastering such a great technique.

Even though he was one of the great legendary Sannin, why was he unable to master the Sage mode completely? Any reason other than the above.

Comment: Two toads are for Jiraya to remain in sage mode continuously and gather natural energy not because he had toad like appearance

Comment: for the title question answer is he was not able to master it,but you description doesn't seem to ask the same question, try to edit and add the question you want to ask

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't mean because he is a Legendary Sannin he had to be able to do that. There are some skills about chakra gathering that he couldn't fully undestand as Naruto did. This question it's answered by you 
"This appearance is due to Jiraiya not having complete mastery over the technique."

Comment: He is a great ninja, but it doesn't mean he have to master every single jutsu perfectly. Besides, him not mastering Sage technique is very likely because Kishimoto-sensei wanted to show that Naruto has passed him. If he mastered sage tech, it would be hard to show that Naruto has passed him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The title great Legendary Sannin does not mean theat he was the master of all types of techniques. He has sealing jutsus, summonings, body activation, combination techniques and is a pretty darn awesome Ninja. He did master the Sage techniques, he just couldn't perfect it.

Naruto surpasses Jiraiya as a Sage because of the nature of Sage chakra. It has to be in balance with the other two types of chakra in you. The balance was slightly tending towards Senjutsu chakra for Jiraiya and hence the toad like appearance, doesn't mean he didn't master how to use it.

Naruto mastered it too, but with the balance being perfect. Also, his clone training technique gave him 4 times more practice [exponentially more] than what Jiraiya was able to spare during his missions and travels. So it is possible that's a reason he was able to perfect it. Surpassing his master meant the perfect balance of chakra without any frog features according to sage Fukasaku.

They both were masters of Senjutsu, as they were able to use it without becoming a toad, were able to perform Kawazu kumite [excuse me if that's a typo] and giant rasengans.
HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Jiraiya didn't master Sage Mode by plot from Kishi. I mean Sage jutsu is just another technique a bright ninja can master even without large chakra reserves (Minato too had toad sage mode)
In my opinion Naruto never surpassed Jiraiya. I mean, we all know the dynamics of kage bunshin upon which naruto relied a lot during his sage training, and resengan training. The advantage naruto had was his mother's bloodline (Uzumaki) which genetically gave him access to vast chakra reserves. vast chakra reserves are needed to be a jinchuuriki( see conversation between 8-tails and his old jinchuuriki, see conversation between 8 tails and the jinchuuriki that killer-bee succeeded, see conversation between killer-bee and naruto in the tailed beast transformation training arc) with little danger since bijuu chakra has the tendency of 'possesing' the jinchuuriki.

Answer (score 0):

He was simply incapable of **Balancing** his Sage Chakra with Physical and Spiritual Energy, That's why he's considered an **Imperfect Sage Mode User**

Naruto on the other hand perfected it because he's capable of balancing 3 Energies